# Unable to display expected result using putchar(ch)

Tags: c

I am new to C programming :D.

This is the Programming Project 7.1 in C Programming - A Modern Method. For example, the input first and last name are Lloyd Fosdick, the expected result should be Fosdick, L. I tried counting the number of characters in the first name (which is 5 in this case). Then, when i > the length of the first name, start printing by using putchar(), as illustrated by the code below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    char ch, first_ini;
    int len1 = 0, i = 0;
    printf("Enter a first and last name: ");
    ch = getchar();
    first_ini = ch;
    printf("The name is: ");
    while (ch != ' '){
        len1++;
        ch = getchar();
    }
    while (ch != '\n')
    {
        i++;
       if (i <= len1) {
            ch = getchar();
        }
        else {
            putchar(ch);
            ch = getchar();
        }

    }
    printf(", %c", first_ini);
    return 0;
}
```

The result I got was ick, L. instead of Fosdick, L

Comment: It seems to be doing what you told it to do. It starts copying the last name at the fifth letter. If you want to output the last name starting at the beginning, why tell it to skip?

Comment: Ah I get what you meant: the ch variable had already been assigned a different value before I called the second while loop. Let me modify the code a little bit and see if I can get the expected result. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try the following changes to your code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    char ch, first_ini;
    int len1 = 0, i = 0;
    printf("Enter a first and last name: ");
    ch = getchar();
    first_ini = ch;
    printf("The name is: ");
    while (ch != ' '){
        len1++;
        ch = getchar();
    }
    while (ch != '\n')
    {
        ch = getchar();// get the characters of second word
        if(ch != '\n')
            putchar(ch);// print the characters of second word but avoid newline
    }
    printf(", %c", first_ini);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem with your code was that it started printing the characters of second word only when the length of second word became greater than the first word.

Comment: Thank you @Adarsh Anurag, thats what I did and now my code runs as expected.